# Will the RaspberryPi Operate Correctly in a refridgerated, 60*F (15*C) Temperatures?

Tags: temperature

Update: I've done this for over two years and haven't had any issues at all. It is fine.

---

I use the RPi to measure the temperature of homebrew beer. I currently just brew in my closet, but I would like to buy a chest-freezer/refridgerator which would combat the heat during the summer (temperature is arguably the most important variable to control for in brewing).

It would be much easier for me if I could place the RPi inside of the chest freezer, which I would set at 55-60*F. Can a RPi withstand this temperature without degrading more than it would otherwise?

I do realize that over the winter my apartment went much lower than 60*F; however, this wasn't a 24/7/365 constant, but only during night times.

Comment: I would suggest you attach your Pi to the outside of the fridge and use a temperature sensor with a lead. This way you can create a small hole in the rubber outline of the fridge door and insert your sensor. This would be a good safety measure if you ever run into a situation where the fermenter bubbles over

Comment: As an added note to the responses below, consider putting your Pi in a very confined (read: nearly sealed) case. This will help it to create a micro-environment due to the heat dissipated from the Pi. This will help minimise the effects of moisture and temperature on the Pi.

Comment: I would also consider selling it against moisture. Condensation seems like it might be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All electronic components used in the Raspberry Pi will at least be specified for the common ["commercial" temperature range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_temperature#Ranges) (0°C to 85°C). (I don't know much about the manufacturer's supply chain, but it is virtually impossible to buy even average quality parts that are not specified to withstand that range.)

Some components, e.g. electrolytic capacitors, will have a decreased life expectancy when they're constantly operated at temperatures near the (mostly upper) limits of their specification, but 15°C is temperate enough not to have any noticeable effects.

Note: This goes for the Raspberry Pi itself. Cheap power supplies might and any type of batteries *will* suffer from reduced efficiency at 15°C.

Answer (score 3):

That temperature shouldn't be a problem. Just watch out for humidity. Especially when you remove it from the cold environment and put it in the warm one. Water vapor in the warm air will condensate on the pi. And water and electricity don't mix. Leaving it unplugged while it get up to temperature prevents any damage from happening.

Happy brewing.