# Protecting the RPi against Moisture in a Refrigerator

Tags: temperature, safety

Refrigerator

This is a follow up to my previous question [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/will-the-raspberrypi-operate-correctly-in-a-refridgerated-60f-15c-temperatu).

My chest freezer came in yesterday, and I brewed two batches of homebrew and placed them in last night. This morning, I couldn't wait any longer so I put my RPi in the fridge and connected the DS18B20 temperature probes into the fermenting wort.

When I run my fingers against one of the walls of the refrigerator, I can detect a good bit of moisture.

How can I protect against the moisture in the refrigerator?

Comment: if you have a cable to power the pi into the refridgerator, then why don't you place the pi outside and connect only the sensor?

Comment: @Gotschi each RPi will have 5 DS18B20 temperature probes measuring the temperature of beer, and these probes are not long enough for me to situate the RPi outside of the refrigerator.

Comment: then make them longer? all you need is to solder 3 wires ;)

Comment: Why not just get an [air-tight case](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105/can-i-use-an-airtight-case)?

Comment: Also see http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=57428